# Unique key for nodes and relationship property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say I have a graph structure like:

```
:Project{name:"str"} -[:BelongsTo]-> :Organisation{id: "str"}
```

I want to ensure that the project `name` is unique for a given organisation `id`. Is it possible to do this within this structure, or do I need to store the `organisationId` as a property in the `:Project` node too? What is the best practice for this type of requirement?

Comment: Storing `organisationId` within the `Project` nodes is the best way forward.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor maybe you put that as an answer and I close this?

Answer (score 0):

You can store `organisationId` within the `Project` nodes and create a constraint like this:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT organisationId_project_name IF NOT EXISTS
FOR (n:Project)
REQUIRE (n.name, n.organisationId) IS UNIQUE
```